# sql WITH couse + upsert = error(command cannot affect row a second time)

Tags: sql, postgresql

Postgresql

I try to use UPSERT from another table in next way:

```
    WITH out_user_a AS(
      UPDATE user_a
      SET inactive = TRUE
      where (visit IS NULL OR purchase IS NULL) AND inactive = FALSE
      AND user_id = 136209
      RETURNING user_guid
    ),
    new_user_a AS (
      INSERT INTO user_a(user_guid, user_id, created_at, updated_at, next_update_at)
      SELECT DISTINCT ON (user_guid) user_guid, 136209, NOW(), NOW(), CURRENT_DATE + 60 FROM out_user_a
      ON CONFLICT (user_id, next_update_at) DO UPDATE SET
    updated_at= NOW(), inactive=FALSE
      RETURNING *
    ) SELECT * FROM new_user_a
```

and I get error `ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE command cannot affect row a second time`

It works well if I use `VALUES()` instead of `SELECT ... FROM ...`

So what I can to do in this case, pls help ...

Comment: I think, your DO UPDATE SET is missing a WHERE.